# How to check if ssh automatic login is setup between two machines?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, ssh, automatic-logon

I have a cluster of 50 machines and some machines already have ssh automatic login setup but I want to be able to check this with a script. Is there a command that help me do this.

Comment: "Automatic login" does not have a definition with regards to SSH. You will need to supply your definition.

Answer (score 1):

that one;

```
list="host1 host2 host3";for host in list;do 
 echo -n $host"  ";ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no  user@$host;
 echo "works!";
done|
grep works
```